# What is the maximum size of an integer (x86)?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, integer, win64

I'm going to upgrade my VC++ 2008 into VC++ 2010 or 2012. Before upgrading I have some questions:

- My compiler only supports the largest `__int64` integers. Is `__int128` supported in version VC++ 2010, 2012 and so on?
- My current compiler doesn't support something like `_WIN64` or `_WIN32` to check the Windows platform. But I doubt `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS` is an another solution; It will be `64` if it's run in Win32, or `128` otherwise. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

In the C++ standard there is a dedicated section for what you want, in short there is [`<limits>` and the included methods](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) that are a solution to your problem.

EDIT: I'm assuming that you want some kind of standardize support, otherwise you should simply refer to the online docs for your compiler

Comment: @xersi simply wants to know the capabilities of the various compilers listed.

Answer (score 1):

For all of the compilers that you mention, 64 bit integer types exist for both 32 and 64 bit targets. However, there are no 128 bit integer types. So, `_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS` evaluates to 64 for all of the listed compilers, and for both 32 and 64 bit targets.

The best you can do is probably to use the SSE2 intrinsic [`__m128i`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26232t5c.aspx) but that depends on the presence of an SSE2 unit on the processor. But you don't need to upgrade to be able to use that. It's available in VS2008 also.